# Having Cucumber feature, find methods implementing it

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have a project in Java that utilises Cucumber BDD.
I have .feature file with scenarios and I know that they are implemented. But stepDefinition file that implements them doesn't have methods that cover "^Given*" part.

How can I find related implementation methods from Scenario text, not writing myself a regex in the search query. So that I could select required text and all methods whose regex matches this text would appear?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: In IntelliJ if you do a CTRL+Click from the scenario step definition you should be taken to the implementation code. IntelliJ also has auto-completion support for Cucumber so when you start typing a step in the feature file it should show you the existing definitions. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @AndréBarbosa indeed! I didn't know that Ctrl+click works for regEx